# Open MPI C++ Link Error (MPI::Datatype::Free) on Windows

Tags: c++, mpi

I'm trying to build a simple Open MPI application for Windows. I've installed the binaries for OpenMPI-v1.6.2 (64-bit). I've also installed Visual Studio 2010. The machine(s) are Windows 7 x64.

When I attempt to compile a simple program that uses MPI::Send(), I get a linker error saying that it cannot resolve MPI::Datatype::Free().

Here's a minimal example:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    MPI::Init(argc,argv);

    // Meant to run with 2 processes.
    if (MPI::COMM_WORLD.Get_rank() == 0) {
        int data;
        MPI::COMM_WORLD.Recv(&data,1,MPI_INT,1,0);
        std::cout << "received " << data << std::endl;
    } else {
        int data = 0xdead;
        std::cout << "sending " << data << std::endl;
        MPI::COMM_WORLD.Send(&data,1,MPI_INT,0,0);
    }

    MPI::Finalize();
}
```

When I compile it:

```
mpic++ send_compile.cpp -o send_compile.exe -DOMPI_IMPORTS -DOPAL_IMPORTS -DORTE_IMPORTS 


Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

cl : Command line warning D9035 : option 'o' has been deprecated and will be removed in a future release
send_compile.cpp
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:send_compile.exe 
/out:send_compile.exe 
"/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\OpenMPI_v1.6.2-x64/lib" 
libmpi_cxx.lib 
libmpi.lib 
libopen-pal.lib 
libopen-rte.lib 
advapi32.lib 
Ws2_32.lib 
shlwapi.lib 
send_compile.obj 
send_compile.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl MPI::Datatype::Free(void)" (?Free@Datatype@MPI@@UEAAXXZ)
send_compile.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

This program compiles and runs without complaint on an Ubuntu machine around here. I don't know what the problem is. Open MPI's documentation didn't say anything about adding the CPP defines (OMPI_IMPORTS, OPAL_IMPORTS, ORTE_IMPORTS) whose absence were causing other linker errors similar to this. I cannot find any information about this particular problem, though.

I tried using dumpbin to get symbols that were in the .lib files installed by MPI, but didn't find any reference to that function name. I didn't find any answers looking in the MPI headers, either.

I have a similar program in C that compiles and runs fine on this Windows machine. I don't know what I'm doing wrong with C++.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: See the exported symbols in `libmpi_cxx.lib`. It could have been compiled with a different C++ compiler which uses different name mangling.

Comment: It turns out (thank you openmpi mailing list) that the answer is not to use new(er) versions of OpenMPI on Windows, as it is no longer supported.